# why is the jquery on handler not working?

Tags: jquery, angular, event-handling

I've successfully ran the onload handler using $(document).ready(function(){...}), but for some reason none of the commands with the on handler are registering at all. I even include an additional function inside the first $() function (using the ready function) that implements the on handler and nothing registers. Here is a snippet of the code I am using incorporating the on handler for both functions.

So far, this has worked:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
$(document).ready(()=>{
this.focusbtn_and_highlight_onClick();
}

    )

}
ngOnDestroy(): void {

}

public focusbtn_and_highlight_onClick(){
console.log('func started');

    $('button')
    .on('click', ()=> {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red')
      // .after('')
      alert("hello")
    })

}
```

But this hasnt:

````
$(document).on('load',function(){
console.log('page loaded');
NavComponent.focusbtn_and_highlight_onClick();
}

    )

}
ngOnDestroy(): void {

}

static focusbtn_and_highlight_onClick(){
console.log('func started');

    $('button')
    .on('click', ()=> {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red')
      // .after('')
      alert("hello")
    })

}```
````

Comment: Why do you need jQuery for handling click event when you could do this natively with angular `(click)`?

Comment: I was trying to use the jquery library to check if the document was ready to interact with animate. This was needed to be done before the click even could be ready to be clicked. And also I figured out the problem .Turns out document doesnt have an on() function, it only supports ready()